# I want to make an app which uses more of Fragments, so which Class to extend in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Now as default AppCompatActivity is extended by default by Android Studio.
But if I am going to use more of fragments, then is it wise to use Fragment Activity or Activity instead of AppCompatActivity ?

On Developer.android site, they mentioned this :

```
↳ android.app.Activity
    ↳ android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        ↳ android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: That depends if you want to use the support [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) or the non-support [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). If you use the non-support version, just use `Activity`, otherwise `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is our simple Activity without action bar.
Fragment is our simple Fragment and FragmentActivity if you want to use getSupportFragmentManager()

ActionbarAcvity if you want to use action bar in activity which is deprecated in 5.0. To support action bar in 5.0 and prior use AppCompatActivity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for all modern app development, since Android 5.0 Lollipop came out and introduced the appcompat library, is to **extend `AppCompatActivity` and use support fragments** (`getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.)

There's no good reason not to; the support and appcompat libraries have caught up to the framework in every feature and boast much wider compatibility.